# How to know how dejadup calls duplicity?

Tags: backup, deja-dup, restore, duplicity

I would like to know how dejadup calls duplicity (like which shell command with args) when ask to create a backup.
I really like dejadup, but I would like to make a more flexible script by directly using duplicity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 like so on the command line:

```
DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 deja-dup --backup
```